# How to create a new database with the hstore extension already installed?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, hstore

Recently [I went into trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11581961/343834) trying to use hstore with Django. I installed hstore this way:

```sql
$ sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
WARNING:  => is deprecated as an operator name
DETAIL:  This name may be disallowed altogether in future versions of PostgreSQL.
CREATE EXTENSION
postgres=# \dx
                           List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |                   Description                    
---------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------
 hstore  | 1.0     | public     | data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(2 rows)
```

And naively thought that my new databases would include hstore. That ain't the case:

```sql
$ createdb dbtest
$ psql -d dbtest -c '\dx'
                 List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |         Description          
---------+---------+------------+------------------------------
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(1 row)
```

Is there a way to automatically have hstore in a newly created database ?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

**Long story short:**

Install hstore in the template1 database:

```bsh
psql -d template1 -c 'create extension hstore;'
```

---

**Step-by-step explanation:**

As stated by [the PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html):

> CREATE EXTENSION loads a new extension into the current database.

Installing an extension is database-specific. The following returns you the current database name:

```bsh
$ psql -c 'select current_database()'
 current_database 
------------------
 username
(1 row)
```

In case you have a database named after your username. Now with `dbtest`:

```bsh
$ psql -d dbtest -c 'select current_database()'
 current_database 
------------------
 dbtest
(1 row)
```

Ok, you got it. Now, to create new databases with hstore installed, you'll have to install it in the `template1` database. According to [the doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html):

> CREATE DATABASE actually works by copying an existing database. By default, it copies the standard system database named template1.

Let's do this:

```bsh
$ psql -d template1 -c 'create extension hstore;'
```

And check that it works :

```bsh
$ createdb dbtest
$ psql -d dbtest -c '\dx'
                 List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |                   Description                    
---------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------
 hstore  | 1.0     | public     | data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(2 rows)
```

Done!

Comment: +1 for being correct and putting it all in a useful format. One might consider to use a different database than `template1`. Any database can serve as template: `CREATE DATABASE foo TEMPLATE mytemplate`. Or, once you have additional stuff in `template1`, you can use the (empty by default) `template0`.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember, that hstore is in the Public schema, so if you use other schemas, you should use format public.hstore(record)