# postgres hstore exists and doesn't exist at same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I set up a Rails app on a remote server and created an hstore extension

```
 sudo -u postgres psql
 CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

I then deployed an iteration of the app that uses hstore in one of the postgres tables, but when it ran the migrations it gave an error message

```
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist
```

I then tried to do this again

```
 sudo -u postgres psql
 CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

but it told me hstore already exists

```
ERROR:  extension "hstore" already exists
```

and this circle continued on.

Any idea what might be causing this problem? I'm using postgres 9.1 on an Ubuntu 12.04 server

**Update**
Note, wondering if this issue was related to permissions, I tried to check my permissions like this but got the following error

```
sudo -u postgres psql -U username
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "username"
```

**Update**
Although hstore is installed, it's not an extension for the database I'm using. How to install it in a specific database?

```
psql -d db_production -c '\dx'
                 List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |         Description          
---------+---------+------------+------------------------------
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.  It just needs a better title such as, "Type 'hstore' does not exist for ActiveRecord Table"

Simply add "execute 'create extension hstore'" just above the create_table command in the ActiveRecord::Migration and redo the migration.

No need to open a separate psql session.

This is yet another example of why Rails is so awesome. Easy Peasy.

Comment: I agree: it does not appear to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To create extension in your database, you have to explicitly connect to that database. So, if your database is `my_app_development`, you have to do :

```
sudo -u postgres psql my_app_development
create extension hstore;
```

Also, you do not tell which rails version you're on. If you're not on rails-4, you will have to use the [postgres hstore gem](https://github.com/diogob/activerecord-postgres-hstore).

Comment: I have tried your steps but still its saying `ERROR:  extension "hstore" already exists`.

Answer (score 7):

Using this SO answer [How to create a new database with the hstore extension already installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584749/how-to-create-a-new-database-with-the-hstore-extension-already-installed?rq=1), I found out that I had to create the extension for the template1 database and then any other database I created thereafter would have it installed

Comment: No—see @I3x's comment.  That should work fine.