# PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR: type "hstore" does not exist but it does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

First of all, this may look like a duplicate of:

[postgres hstore exists and doesn't exist at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467481/postgres-hstore-exists-and-doesnt-exist-at-same-time)

but it is not. While I am getting the same error message in the circumstance. When checking to see if hstore is installed on the DB, we can see that it is:

```
./psql -d photographerio_development -c '\dx'
                       List of installed extensions
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |                   Description                    
---------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------
 hstore  | 1.2     | hstore     | data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
```

and it is too on the template_1 DB.

So, when I try to run the migration to add the hstore, I get the `PG::Error: ERROR:  extension "hstore" already exists` and when I comment out this migration, on the next one, which requires the hstore, it says `PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist` which is a bit of a paradox.

It is a Rails 4.0.1 app with postgresql 9 and I have hstore working on a few other projects running on this machine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have installed the `hstore` extension in a schema named `hstore` which is presumably not on your default `search_path`.

You must do one of these:

- Add `hstore` to `search_path` during connection setup;
- Add `hstore` to `search_path` with an `ALTER USER ... SET` or `ALTER DATABASE ... SET`;
- Move the hstore extension from the `hstore` schema into `public`; or
- schema-qualify all references to `hstore`, e.g. `hstore.hstore(...)`. This must be done for operators too; `->` becomes `OPERATOR(hstore.->)`

Comment: Adding it to the search_path was the easiest way to fix this.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I solved the problem.
Create a schema called extensions and grant authorization to the db username you use in the project.

```
psql -U postgres -d template1 -c "CREATE SCHEMA extensions AUTHORIZATION <yourDbUserName>;"
```

create the extensions in the created schema (extensions)

```
psql -U postgres -d template1 -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore SCHEMA extensions;"
```

Comment: The `AUTHORIZATION` was the part I was missing, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved this issue in ubuntu 18.04.

1. Provide postgres super user access.

   sudo su postgres
2. Then I run:

   psql -U postgres *your_database_name* -c 'create extension hstore;'

Now I can alter table your_database_name and add hstore type columns in it.

- Connect to your database

  psql -d *your_database_name* -U *your_user_role*

And

```
alter table your_table_name add your_column_name HSTORE;
```

Though there might be saveral different ways to do it, but I solve it in this way.

Hope this will help novice users like me.

Comment: aka. `create extension hstore`