# Travis ci, Rails and Postgresql - ERROR type hstore does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, travis-ci

I'm getting:

```
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist
LINE 1: ...arying(255), "finish" timestamp, "widget_locations" hstore)
```

Below is my Travis config file:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.0.0
env:
  - DB=postgresql
script: 
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
  - bundle exec rspec spec/
before_script:
  - cp config/database.travis.yml config/database.yml
  - psql -c 'create database virtual_test' -U postgres
  - psql virtual_test -c 'CREATE EXTENSION hstore' -U postgres
bundler_args: --binstubs=./bundler_stubs
before_install:
  - bundle update debugger-ruby_core_source
```

I also have below migrations file:

```
class SetupHstore < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore'
  end
  def self.down
    execute 'DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS hstore'
  end
end
```

This however creates the error regardless.

Is there something wrong here?

Comment: Do try enable `hstore` from `psql` console : `CREATE EXTENSION hstore`

Comment: I already have `before_script` command `  - psql virtual_test -c 'CREATE EXTENSION hstore' -U postgres` is this ok?

Answer (score 1):

Might be too late with this but encountered the same problem. Changed hstore create to this:

```
 - psql virtual_test -c 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore' -U postgres
```

And rake db:test:prepare to this:

```
 - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

Its weird but it worked, might help you out as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by a `search_path` issue as described in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21910573/179316

Answer (score 0):

Change your `before_script` to this:

```
before_script:
  - psql template1 -c 'create extension hstore;'
  - cp config/database.travis.yml config/database.yml
  - psql -c 'create database virtual_test' -U postgres
```

Note that we're creating an extension on the first line.