# ltree extension installed, but create table still throws error

Tags: postgresql

I added the ltree extension and I can see the extension in my db but when I run the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE flight_office.document_folder (
document_folder_id serial8,
name varchar,
path ltree,
PRIMARY KEY (document_folder_id) 
);
```

I get this:
ERROR:  type "ltree" does not exist

Comment: When you say you "added" it, what exactly did you do? Show the steps taken please.

Comment: I see you use at least one non default schema `flight_office` -- if you work with multiple schemas, make sure you specify fully qualified names for types (f.ex. `public.ltree` if the extension is created within the `public` schema) or (preferably) always include the schema where you created your extensions into the `search_path` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909417/pgundefinedobject-error-type-hstore-does-not-exist-but-it-does

Comment: I'm just starting on Postgres (coming from MySQL) and it seems I need to take more time to better understand schemas. Thanks pozs.

Comment: @pozs the problem was in fact my schema. Once I deleted it and stuck with public and added the extension it worked fine. Not sure how to best to deal with this question and your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Probably your schema is not included in the `search_path`.

To install the `ltree` extension in a schema different from `public` there are some steps to be done. Let's say your schema is called "myschema":

First create the schema and install the extension:

```
CREATE SCHEMA myschema;

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS ltree
WITH SCHEMA myschema;
```

You can check the last step with

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.schemata
WHERE schema_name = 'myschema';

SELECT * 
FROM pg_available_extensions
WHERE name = 'ltree';
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_extension;

select *
from pg_catalog.pg_namespace;
```

where `extowner` indicates what is the schema where the extension is available.

Then, check whether `myschema` belongs to the `search_path`:

```
SHOW search_path;
```

; if not add your schema to it:

```
SET search_path TO "$user", public, myschema;
```

the latter set the `search_path` only for the session. If you want to set it permanently use

```
ALTER DATABASE <DATABASE_NAME> SET search_path TO "$user", public, myschema;
```

Finally try to create a table:

```
create table myschema.temptable (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    path ltree UNIQUE
);
```

and add some values:

```
INSERT INTO myschema.temptable (id, path)
values (1, 'root');
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by @pozs, EXTENSION should be added along with the schema,The following worked for me:

```
CREATE EXTENSION  IF NOT EXISTS  LTREE
     WITH   SCHEMA  schema_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

This also works. It will create the extension for the public schema, if no schema is specified.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS ltree;
```