# PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR: version to install must be specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Attempting to migrate the [Discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/) database, but [20120921162512_add_meta_data_to_forum_threads.rb](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/db/migrate/20120921162512_add_meta_data_to_forum_threads.rb) seems to produce the following error:

```
== 20120921162512 AddMetaDataToForumThreads: migrating ========================
-- execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  version to install must be specified
: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore/usr/home/www/_myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
/usr/home/www/_myapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this issue is by having your default Postgres template database already have the `hstore` extension installed, like this:

`psql -d template1 -c 'create extension hstore;'`

See this answer for a great, thorough explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11584751/483260