# Installing hstore extension in django nose tests

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nose, hstore

I've installed the hstore extension successfully, and everything works when I `syncdb`. (I'm using [djorm-ext-hstore](https://github.com/niwibe/djorm-ext-hstore))

However, nose creates a new temp database to run tests in, and hstore is not installed in it.

I need to run `CREATE EXTENSION HSTORE;` on the test db right before nose syncs the db, but I can't find any info on how to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of pain by creating the extension on the `template1` postgres database. Then any database you create after that will have the HSTORE extension.

Comment: rantaplan, that should have been the answer!

Comment: It's OK, I usually avoid giving one-line answers. Glad I helped.

Comment: when the answer is a one-liner, it's legit! Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 26):

This is a non-issue: The best way to fix this is to apply the hstore extension on the default database, `template1`

`psql -d template1 -c 'create extension hstore;'`

Reference: [How to create a new database with the hstore extension already installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584749/how-to-create-a-new-database-with-the-hstore-extension-already-installed)

Answer (score 8):

With Django 1.8 (which is outdated now, but it still exists in 3.2):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import HStoreExtension

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ...

    operations = [
        HStoreExtension(),
        ...
    ]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield

EDIT: Just note that there is also a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) which handles (un)marshalling of json already and inline search. The HStoreExtension is not necessary for it. Requires Django >=1.11 and Postgres >=9.4.

Comment: This should be the first operation in the first migration - before the migrations that perform any hstore related operation.

Comment: This is a great answer and the only downside is that it requires manually editing/modifying a migration (at least in my case). I wonder why this isn't done as part of the initial migration when an `hstore` column is first used?

Comment: Installing extensions requires superuser privileges in postgres. You might choose to install the extension outside of the regular Django setup to avoid giving your Django system these privileges.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're using [django-nose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-nose).  In this case you should create your own `TestSuiteRunner`:

```
from django.db import connections, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
from django_nose import NoseTestSuiteRunner

class MyTestSuiteRunner(NoseTestSuiteRunner):
    def setup_databases(self):
        result = super(MyTestSuiteRunner, self).setup_databases()

        connection = connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS]
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('CREATE EXTENSION HSTORE')

        return result
```

Then in `settings.py` you should specify your custom test runner:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'path.to.my.module.MyTestSuiteRunner'
```

Comment: Thank you! Without running that, I can see a problem: If setup_databases() actually creates the tables. Shouldn't we create the extension first?

Comment: I'll let you know when I run it.

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid, if I put the create extension first, the test database isn't there, and if I put it after the super, it is never run, because that's where the error takes place. :-/

Comment: It works also with DiscoverRunner (django.test.runner)

Answer (score 4):

Since my last answer, Django deprecated and removed `pre_syncdb` signal. I've updated the answer to accommodate more recent versions. The basic mechanics are identical for newer versions as both methods rely on signals and the SQL code that only executes if HSTORE extension does not exist.

## Django 1.8+

Since Django introduced DB migrations, `pre_syncdb` signals were [*marked deprecated in 1.7*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_syncdb) and [**completely removed in 1.9**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#management-signals). However, they introduced a new signal called [`pre_migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#pre-migrate) which can be used the same way.

```python
"""
This is an example models.py which contains all model definition.
"""
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import connection, models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_migrate
import sys

# The sender kwarg is optional but will be called for every pre_syncdb signal
# if omitted. Specifying it ensures this callback to be called once.
@receiver(pre_migrate, sender=sys.modules[__name__])
def setup_postgres_hstore(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    Always create PostgreSQL HSTORE extension if it doesn't already exist
    on the database before syncing the database.
    Requires PostgreSQL 9.1 or newer.
    """
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore")

# ...rest of your model definition goes here
class Foo(models.Model):
    # ...field definitions, etc.
```

---

## Django 1.6+ (original answer)

My suggestion is to use `pre_syncdb` signal hook.

See my answer on the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577993/how-to-setup-django-hstore-with-an-existing-app-managed-by-south/23625754#23625754).

```python
"""
This is an example models.py which contains all model definition.
"""
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db import connection, models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_syncdb
import sys

# The sender kwarg is optional but will be called for every pre_syncdb signal
# if omitted. Specifying it ensures this callback to be called once.
@receiver(pre_syncdb, sender=sys.modules[__name__])
def setup_postgres_hstore(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    Always create PostgreSQL HSTORE extension if it doesn't already exist
    on the database before syncing the database.
    Requires PostgreSQL 9.1 or newer.
    """
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore")

# ...rest of your model definition goes here
class Foo(models.Model):
    # ...field definitions, etc.
```

The `pre_syncdb` signal is fired before the model table is created, making it ideal to ensure the extension is installed when the test database is being set up every time. The `IF NOT EXISTS` ensures that PostgreSQL ignores the command if the extension is already installed. You'll get an error if you run `CREATE EXTENSION` on an extension that already exists.

This works for the default Django unit test framework and will most likely work for Django nose tests.

More info on signals:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/signals/#management-signals

Answer (score 4):

Also you can run sql command in a migration (Django 1.8):

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    # ...

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL('create extension hstore;'),
        # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's work for me
https://gist.github.com/smcoll/bb2533e4b53ae570e11eb2ab011b887b

```
from django.db.backends.base import creation
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner


class CustomDiscovererRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def setup_databases(self, **kwargs):
        def wrap_create_test_db(function):
            def decorated_create_test_db(self, verbosity, autoclobber, keepdb):
                test_database_name = function(self, verbosity, autoclobber, keepdb)
                self.connection.close()
                self.connection.settings_dict["NAME"] = test_database_name
                cursor = self.connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore')
                return test_database_name

            return decorated_create_test_db
        creation.BaseDatabaseCreation._create_test_db = wrap_create_test_db(
            creation.BaseDatabaseCreation._create_test_db
        )

        return super(CustomDiscovererRunner, self).setup_databases(**kwargs)
```

settings.py

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'my_project.settings_test.CustomDiscovererRunner'
```