# how to create postgres extension with elastic beanstalk, during create/deploy?

Tags: django, postgresql, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, paas

I'm attempting to programatically create an hstore extension for a postgres backed django application. Currently, after creation (via `eb create -database.engine postgres`), I connect to the db instance directly with pgadmin, and create the extension manually.

Is there a way to do this either with options, container commands, a pre-deploy hook, etc? I've been searching fairly hard, and not seen anything that's a guide on this. Or am I just thinking about this process in a backwards way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355895/installing-hstore-extension-in-django-nose-tests Answer number two is what I have used in the past.

Comment: Great! I'll take a look.

Comment: Effectively, I'm trying to do what's refer to what's being done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584749/how-to-create-a-new-database-with-the-hstore-extension-already-installed), but by specifying it on creation in Elastic Beanstalk. So, we'll have to dig some more.